# How to convert bytearray to img tag?

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have a service which returns byte array of png image , I want to render it on my jsp page .
I am making ajax call to get the image.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            url: '<spring:url value="/service/org/flk/2"/>',
            success: function(msg) {
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564119/javascript-convert-byte-to-image

Answer (score 1):

You will need to stream base64 encoded data in response and then you can do it like

```
$("#someDivId").html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+response + '"/>');
```

where `response` is the base64 encoded image data

Comment: my service returns the bytearray , do you mean to assign response which I get from service to attach it to above string